# Gem Install Error Requiring Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Using `ubuntu/trust64`, I'm getting the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/workspace/project$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.................
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.......................................................................
RubyGems 1.8.23 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to RubyGems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Fetching i18n 1.0.0
Installing i18n 1.0.0
Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing i18n (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  activesupport was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    i18n
```

I don't understand the above error since I'm using, as I understand, `ruby 2.4.3`, which is greater than `2.0.0`:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/workspace/project$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Please advise me on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try running these commands

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

I suspect it may be a problem with rubygems rather than your ruby version.